# oracle 11g regular expression pattern

Tags: sql, regex, oracle11g

I have a oracle 11g table. The data in a columnA is RS_X, RS_2, RS_3 etc.

If the data is 'X' after RS_ then the output should be set to '-1'.

can someone please let me know how can I do this.

Thanks
Pavan

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this using REGEX then use this SQL.

```
update my_table
set output = -1
where regexp_like(columnA, '^RS_X')
```

All records with "RS_X" at the beginning of their value in columnA will have the value in output set to -1.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a select decode and substr

```
select decode(substr(columnA, 4,1),'X', -1, columnA) from my_table;
```

or with where condition

```
select  -1  from my_table
where substr(columnA, 4,1) = 'X' ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the below query to get the output -

```
select col1,decode(substr(col1,4,1),'X',-1,1) from test1
```

The output would be like -

```
RS_1    1
RS_2    1
RS_3    1
RS_X   -1
```